# Add and remove class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tab menu, and i want onlick be be added a `class="selected"` - and on click on one of the other tabs, the class should be removed from the current link, and then be added to the link i've clicked on...

I've tried this but didnt work

```
$('.tab-links a').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<section class="tabs">
<nav class="tab-links">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/min+side/Mine+favoritter" class="ajax-tab-fav myoptionstab">MIne favoritter</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/min+side/Mine+jobagenter" class="ajax-tab-jobagents myoptionstab">Jobagenter</a>
    </li>
    <li class="last">
      <a href="/min+side/Rediger+bruger" class="ajax-tab-edituser myoptionstab">Indstillinger</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="clear">
  <!---->
</div>
```

Comment: *does not work* means *the class is toggled only in the clicked link*?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Yes, that's what he meant. The answers below don't work either. I am looking for a solution too.

Answer (score 11):

```
var $links = $('.tab-links a');
$links.click(function(){
   $links.removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

`this` is the target of the click event
`toggleClass` method adds a class if it is not present else removes it.

Therefore when you say `$(this).toggleClass('selected');`, The class is added or removed **only** on the element that was clicked which is clearly not what you want.

Answer (score 9):

Using pure javascript:

```
function toggleItem(elem) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var current = this;
      for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        if (current != elem[i]) {
          elem[i].classList.remove('active');
        } else if (current.classList.contains('active') === true) {
          current.classList.remove('active');
        } else {
          current.classList.add('active')
        }
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  };
}
toggleItem(document.querySelectorAll('.link'));
```

codepen http://codepen.io/8eni/pen/MaGVrq

- Add 'active' class onClick, whilst removing 'active' class from other buttons
- Toggle class onclick

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.tab-links a').click(function(){
    $('.tab-links a').removeClass('selected')
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Using this code, the class will be added only on the element that was clicked and will not effect other elements in question.

Answer (score 1):

The given below is awesome and simplest way for addClass and RemoveClass onClick using pure Javascript.

**Step: 1** - write the following code in .html file

```
//... code here
<h1 id="kiran" onclick="myFunction(e)">A</h1>
<h1 id="kiran" onclick="myFunction(e)">B</h1>
<h1 id="kiran" onclick="myFunction(e)">C</h1>
<h1 id="kiran" onclick="myFunction(e)">D</h1>
//... code here
```

**Step: 2** - Write the following in .js file

```
function handleClick(e) {
        var curr = e.target.textContent;
        var elem = document.querySelectorAll('#kiran');
        for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
            if (elem[i].textContent === curr) {
                elem[i].className = 'active';
            } else {
                elem[i].className = '';
            }
        }
    };
```

**Step: 3** - Write the following in .css file

```
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. try to use this code.

```
$('.footer-right .cu-btn-ol-round').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```