# change class on LI click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to dinamically assign a .selected class to the element where I click and also remove any other previous class asigned to the clicked element so I can change CSS class. Maybe this code:

```
$(this).click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

works but what happend if I click in any other LI? Any help to get this work?

EDIT:
Ok see this code:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

By default none have any classes but I click in Item 2 then the HTML should transform on this one:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li class="selected">Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

but once again if I click in Item 3 then the HTML should transform on this one:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li class="selected">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

This is what I'm trying to do

Comment: Do you want to remove classes from previously clicked li-s?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add and remove class on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077673/add-and-remove-class-on-click)

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest:

```
$(selector).click(function(){
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

With regards to the comment left by moonwave99 (below), if you only want to remove the `selected` class-name from those elements contained within the same `parent` element:

```
$(selector).click(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  that.parent().find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  that.addClass('selected');
});
```

Though it's worth remembering what element you're clicking, and what the parent will be, for example, clicking on the `a` in the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Will look within the `li` for the other `.selected` elements, and so you should use:

```
$(selector).click(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  that.closest('ul').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  that.addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: I'd just narrow the search to `$('.selected', $(this).parent())` in case there are more lists in the page.

Comment: @david-thomas see my edited post, is this the same as you leave on your comments?

Comment: @ReynierPM, the last of the code in the answer should do what you require.

Comment: As far as a bug-report goes, that doesn't help. What doesn't work? Can you show what you're working with in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Just a demo, so I can see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

First remove selected class from all li inside ul and then apply class to clicked li.

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
 $('ul li').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On my travels I discovered that it is not possible to addClass of 'active' to list items in when using bootstrap. So if you are reading this (as I was) wondering why this doesn't work when the classname is 'active' you need to choose something else.