# Collapsible dropdown menu - Set background for menu in active state?

Tags: css

First, please [take a look at this pen](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/GxbBs/) showing just the menu + the code ([preview the menu here](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/GxbBs/embedded/result/)).

**Coming to the point:** In the navbar that you see, clicking on the "Channels" menu shows the menu item sliding out. The problem is, the menu's background doesn't represent its active state (i.e. `#fff` background and `#222` color).

Setting the background-color when the mouse is hovered on the menu, is easy. But this one's tricky. I did try, `:active` selector to no avail. Any ideas?

**SCREENSHOTS:**

[image: no mouse hover screenshot]

[image: menu with mouse hover screenshot]

Comment: You'll likely need to add javascript to the click event to toggle the class with the active styles you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it appears as though using jQuery to add/remove a class is the only way to go, I went ahead with it. Here's the code I used.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.menu-item > a').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
});
```

The code finds the link element `a` one level down the element with `.menu-item` class (`li` in my case), and adds/removes class `.selected` to the link element.

[Here's a fork](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/TzW3m/) of the [original pen](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/GxbBs/) with the menu functioning the way I intended it to. You can preview the new and functioning menu [here](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/TzW3m/embedded/result/).

***(Full credit to the [code provided in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7077673/1071413). More info in the [official jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).)***

**UPDATE:** You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10919473/1071413) extremely helpful (a better, simpler solution).

Example code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.collapse').on('show hide', function () {
        $(this).siblings("a").toggleClass('selected'); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the li once the menu is open and remove it again.

BTW: `:active` works for the moment you click on it.